# Basic Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have a doubt in binomial distribution. 
Assume that a bag contains 5 black balls and 5 white balls. So the probability of drawing one black ball randomly is $\frac{1}{2}$. I want to find the probability of 6 black balls. Let the X be the number of black balls. So by binomial distribution $P(X=6)=\binom{10}{6}\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^6\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{10-6}=0.205$.

But we had only 5 black balls. Probability of getting 6 black should have been $0$. Am I right? Please clarify this doubt.

Comment: Do you draw with or without replacement?

Comment: without replacement.

Comment: Yes, then the prob. is $0$. But without replacement you have to use the Hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: Then why I am getting P(X=6)=0.205 by binomial distribution formula

Comment: It's right, if you assume with replacement. What's your problem with it?

Comment: Oh ok thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: The hypergeometric distribution is used for sampling *without* replacement.

Comment: @user2661923 I agree to Taussig's comment.

Comment: @callculus42 So do I.  That was a typo on my part.  The comment should read: For sampling without replacement, see [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Probability_mass_function).

Comment: @user2661923 OK. Now all is clear now.